# How to use "tel:XXXXXXXX" links from the InAppBrower plugin in Cordova?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3, inappbrowser

I'am working on an Cordova application that loads its web content inside the InAppBorwser plugin webview. The application contains "tel:XXXXXXXXXXXXX" links that cause the Android OS to open the dialer. When the link is clicked, the dialer is opened but the InAppBrowser displays an error page indicating that the web page at tel:XXXXXXXXXX is not available.
Is it possible to fix this issue?
NB: The feature is working correctly when the web content is loaded inside the Cordova default webview and not inside the InAppBrowser.

Comment: Because of security reasons, there is no way to fix this.

Comment: It's a bug on inAppBrowser plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the LOAD START event of the inappbrowser to detect if the URL being opened contains "tel"; then stop the execution before anything happends. Your native dialer should still pop up though.

Comment: And how it's possible to stop the execution before anything happens? I tried event.preventDefault() in the callback of the loadstart event of InAppBrowser but it looks like the loadstart event itself gets executed too late (after the browser attempts to load the page).

Comment: You can't stop the execution per-se; however, you can close the browser altogether, or maybe go back to the previous by pressing the back button or maybe loading the previous page again.